# Ascending order of vector of numeric characters

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers of type character.

```
x = c("5","-.5","-.1",".01",".1","1","3")
```

Is there a quick and easy way to order this character vector using the numeric value of each character? I can't find a clean way to do this.

So for instance, I want a function

```
x <- characterOrder(x)
```

With output:

```
c("-.5","-.1",".01",".1","1","3", "5")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
library(gtools)
mixedsort(x)
#[1] "-.5" "-.1" ".01" ".1"  "1"   "3"   "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in base R using the order function and the as.numeric when you order it by the as.numeric value.

```
x = c("5","-.5","-.1",".01",".1","1","3")
x[order(as.numeric(x))]
[1] "-.5" "-.1" ".01" ".1"  "1"   "3"   "5"
```

If you want this in a function:

```
characterOrder <- function(x) {
  return(x[order(as.numeric(x))])
}
```